# RegExp caret character matched and shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following test (in Javascript regexp):

```
    /[^A-Z^a-z]/.test('^')
```

The return value is `false`.  Why?

Comment: There are only two characters (afaik) that have a special meaning inside a character class, and also only if they appear in specific locations. `^` is special only as first character of the class. It negates the whole class. `-` is special only if it does not appear as first or last character and it specifies a range.

Comment: I'm just surprised I've never inadvertently stumbled across this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it returns correctly. You included also the `^` inside the negated character class.

```
not of ^ == ^
=> false
```

Just remove the `^` which was at the middle of character class to return true. Note that an unescapped or escaped `^` at the middle or at the last of character class would match the literal carrot symbol `^`. For negated character class `[^..]`, it does the opposite thing.

```
> /[^A-Z^a-z]/.test('^')
false
> /[^A-Za-z]/.test('^')
true
```

Comment: Your edit answered my question.  But why doesn't it have to be escaped?

Comment: all the regex special chars will loose it's meaning inside a char class, like `[*.]` matches a literal dot and start. But some chars has special meaning when it was used inside the char class and also it's position also very important. `[^a]` not of a. `[a-z]` matches all the chars from a to z.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is correct because your negated character class negates the caret character as well. Saying, match any character except: `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `^`. You can modify as follows:

```
/[^a-z]/i.test('^') // true
```

Comment: For Sure a better way to do it.  But, still, why doesn't the caret need to be escaped?

Comment: The caret inside of a character class `[^ ]` is the negation operator, which matches anything **NOT** in the character class. If you escape it, the regex engine matches a literal `^` . With having `^` in the middle of a negated character class, it does not need to be escaped since the negation operator is at the beginning of the class.